# Three.js: Camera Collision on Terrain

Tags: camera, three.js, collision, terrain

How should I go about adding camera collision to a terrain in three.js.

The terrain is from 'mrdoob's three.js' examples and is randomly generated and I am currently converting it to height map.

I am thinking of implementing the collision as follows:

- Create a 'box' object around the camera
- If the box object is not touching the terrain, move the camera down.
- If the box object IS touching the terrain, keep the Y axis of the camera.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory is that you send a ray from the location you are (camera position) straight down. You find the intersection point and based on the distance you decide what to do. Implementation wise I cannot help you but THREE.Ray should help you.